# Non-rectangle select in Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, copy-paste

Is there *any* way I can disable the stupid rectangle selection mode thing in the Windows command line? I want to select line by line like normal. Currently it's a giant pain when I need to copy things that span multiple lines because the copied text gets lineendings where there shouldn't be any...

Comment: Pipe anything that do at the command line to a text file then select in notepad.

Answer (score 6):

There is [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/) - configurable and flexible windows console emulator, I'm the author of it.

**ConEmu allows both rectangular (block) and stream (text) selection.**

- Using mouse just start dragging (with <kbd>LeftBtn</kbd> pressed) over console in **vertical direction** to begin **block** selection and in **horizontal direction** to begin **text/stream** selection;
- With keyboard you may start **block** selection with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>/<kbd>DownArrow</kbd> and **text** selection with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LeftArrow</kbd>/<kbd>RightArrow</kbd>. Press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> if you want to set up your own hotkeys for that actions;
- From [System menu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/SystemMenu) or [Tab menu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/TabMenu) -> `Edit` -> `Mark block`, `Mark text` or `Copy all`;
- At last, you may use modifiers (choose from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>) to start exact type of selection. By default, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftBtn</kbd> and use mouse drag to start **block** selection, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LeftBtn</kbd> and use mouse drag to start **text** selection.

**Copy format**

You may choose *plain text* or *HTML* (to paste colors/fonts into blogs etc).

**Some useful answers**

are here in the [ConEmu tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conemu). And user comments on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560).

**A brief excerpt from the long list of options**

- Tabs and splits for running any shell you choose
- Use any font installed in the system, or copied to a folder of the program (ttf, otf, fon, bdf)
- Run selected tabs as Administrator (Vista+) or as selected user
- Windows 7 Jump lists and Progress on taskbar
- Integration with [DosBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560) (useful in 64bit systems to run DOS applications)
- Smooth resize, maximized and fullscreen window modes
- Scrollbar initially hidden, may be revealed by mouseover or checkbox in settings
- Optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications
- User friendly text and block selection (from keyboard or mouse), copy, paste, text search in console
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 color

For more information you may refer to ConEmu [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/TableOfContents) or [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/conemu_ml).

Comment: Answer updated, all possibilities explained.

Comment: looks good, it's a multi-tab FAR Manager. Have you considered adding Linux-commands support. It's done in CmdEr, but copypasting is so much better in Far/ConEmu.

Comment: There is no need to "add" Linux command support. Just use them. There are several options - wsl, cygwin, msys, etc.

Answer (score 4):

With the standard command prompt no. It is possible though with an alternative command prompt such as [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/). It will also allow you to freely set the the window size, have multiple tabs etc.

Comment: it's possible with the standard command prompt now in Windows 10